# Flutter: Updating the percent value of LinearPercentIndicator using Function call across 2 Separate classes

Tags: flutter

I have a function present in a separate class that uploads a file and gives a callback: (progress). I am trying to grab the progress value and use it to update LinearPercentIndicator. Problem is, they both are present in separate classes.

The value/progress I want to get is present in the following code:

```dart
_uploadToLG(String localPath, String projectname) async {
    dynamic credencials = await _getCredentials();
     // some code
      // upload kml
      await client.connectSFTP();
      await client.sftpUpload(
        path: localPath,
        toPath: '/var/www/html',
        callback: (progress) {
          print('Sent $progress');

          _SendtoLGState()._loader(progress); // I am using this line to grab the desired value
        },
      );
      return await client.execute(
          'echo "flytoview=${flyto.generateLinearString()}" > /tmp/query.txt');
    } 
  }
```

Now in the desired SendtoLG class which is a stateful widget I got:

```dart
dynamic _percentdata = 5;
  Future<void> _loader(dynamic progress) async {
    setState(() {
      _percentdata = progress; // _percentdata is a  successfully able to get value of progress as it updates.
    });
  }
```

The problem is using setState above gives me an error.

```
E/flutter ( 1545): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor: _SendtoLGState#48306(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 1545): This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.
```

Lastly LinearPercentIndicator is defined as follows:

```dart
LinearPercentIndicator(
             animation: true,
             lineHeight: 68.0,
             percent: _percentdata / 100, // It fails to update as setState fails to work.
             center: new Text(
             _percentdata.toString() + "%",
             style: new TextStyle(
             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
             color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 40.0),
             ),
             barRadius: ui.Radius.circular(40),
             progressColor: Colors.greenAccent,
             )
```

**Okay So I tried the ValueListenableBuilder approach, It doesn't give me an error but it doesn't work either as the LinearPercentIndicator stayed at 0.**

In the function of separate class I used:

```dart
class LGConnection {
 ValueNotifier valueNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);
_uploadToLG(String localPath, String projectname) async {
    dynamic credencials = await _getCredentials();
     // some code
      // upload kml
      await client.connectSFTP();
      await client.sftpUpload(
        path: localPath,
        toPath: '/var/www/html',
        callback: (progress) {
          print('Sent $progress');

         // _SendtoLGState()._loader(progress);
            valueNotifier.value = progress; // I am using this line to grab the desired value
        },
      );
      return await client.execute(
          'echo "flytoview=${flyto.generateLinearString()}" > /tmp/query.txt');
    } 
  } 
}
```

Now in the desired SendtoLG class which is a stateful widget I got:

```dart
LGConnection appValueNotifier = LGConnection(); // I just added this
```

Now the LinearPercentIndicator looks like:

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
     valueListenable: appValueNotifier.valueNotifier,
                      builder: (context, value, child) {
                      return LinearPercentIndicator(
                          animation: true,
                          lineHeight: 68.0,
                          percent: double.parse(value.toString()) / 100,
                          center: new Text(
                          value.toString() + "%",
                          style: new TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 40.0),
                          ),
                          barRadius: ui.Radius.circular(40),
                          progressColor: Colors.greenAccent,
           );
     })
```

Comment: i would suggest to use something link an inherited widget(provider for example) or u can use a more simpler approach using a ValueListnableBuilder to do your work the issue here is u are trying to call ` _SendtoLGState()._loader(progress);`  in your method, the widget that this state belongs might not be alive when u call setState

Comment: Okay I am going to try ValueListnableBuilder approach , hopefully it takes value of progress whenever it changes.. do I get rid of setState which is wrapped around _percentdata = progress?

Comment: it would be better if u can create a gist so with all the files that u mentioned about so we can help u out better

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yashrajbharti/6df31f1c0b978a7289219c5f6859f0de here is the gist, but the problem is its too much of code, and a special setup to SSH into to upload the KML files. The above code snippet in my question is the simpler version with reduced code.

Comment: Okay so I changed the approach to ValueListnableBuilder  but the value of LinearPercentIndicator stays at 0. I don't get any error but the value doesn't update either. I will add the suitable changes I made in the Question itself